# How to evenly space edges to make a car rooftop?

Tags: modeling

I model a car and I want to make a rooftop first of all. I would like to make it like this:

[image]

How to evenly space the edges to make what I want?

Comment: Do your edges need to be even, or those specific lengths? You can even a series of edges by selecting them and using LoopTools > Space to even out their lengths.

Comment: Yes, this does.